# Laundered Pajamas for Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, clothing, washing-clothes

The Ohr L'Tzion (2:16:2) [writes](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19979&st=&pgnum=170) based on the Shulchan Aruch OC (242:1) that a person should wear clean clothes on Shabbos if the garment directly touches the body and becomes sweaty, but outerwear doesn't require to be newly laundered each week unless they became dirty.

מתקנת עזרא לכבס בגדיו לשבת בכל שבוע. אמנם אין צריך לכבס אלא את הבגדים שנוגעים בגוף ומתלכלכים בזיעה תדיר, כגון הבגדים הפנימיים והחולצה, אבל המכנסיים והבגד העליון אין צריך לכבס בכל שבוע, אלא רק כשהם מלוכלכים.

If someone wears pajamas which do not become dirty although they are worn directly on the body, (i.e. only worn for a short time, only after being showered, in the cold winter weeks) would he be required to have freshly laundered night garments for Shabbos?

Comment: See Yabia Omer chelek 9: page 363: סיכום, not directly related to your question ,but very imp when learning that specific chelek

Comment: I believe that the answer is within the teshuva itself ,if it becomes dirty then yes,if not, not

Comment: @sam I thought the same way, but was wondering if Poskim said as much outright